# Calculating the average of Sensor Data (Capacitive Sensor)

Tags: math, arduino, microcontroller, capacity

So I am starting to mess around with Capacitive sensors and all because its some pretty cool stuff.

I have followed some tutorials online about how to set it up and use the CapSense library for Arduino and I just had a quick question about this code i wrote here to get the average for that data.

```
void loop() {                    
  long AvrNum;
  int counter = 0;

  AvrNum += cs_4_2.capacitiveSensor(30);
  counter++;

  if (counter = 10) {
    long AvrCap = AvrNum/10;
    Serial.println(AvrCap);
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

This is my loop statement and in the Serial it seems like its working but the numbers just look suspiciously low to me. I'm using a 10M resistor (brown, black, black, green, brown) and am touching a piece of foil that both the send and receive pins are attached to (electrical tape) and am getting numbers around about 650, give or take 30.

Basically I'm asking if this code looks right and if these numbers make sense...?

Comment: No it is not right. `AvrNum` is used uninitalised so results in Undefined Behaviour. And `counter = 10` should be `counter == 10`.

Comment: and strictly, the code would be better with `long AvrCap = AvrNum/counter;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language used in the Arduino environment is really just an unenforced subset of C++ with the `main()` function hidden inside the framework code supplied by the IDE. Your code is a module that will be compiled and linked to the framework. When the framework starts running it first initializes itself then your module by calling the function `setup()`. Once initialized, the framework enters an infinite loop, calling your modules function `loop()` on each iteration.

Your code is using local variables in `loop()` and expecting that they will hold their values from call to call. While this might happen in practice (and likely does since that part of framework's `main()` is probably just `while(1) loop();`), this is invoking the demons of Undefined Behavior. C++ does not make any promises about the value of an uninitialized variable, and even reading it can cause anything to happen. Even apparently working.

To fix this, the accumulator `AvrNum` and the `counter` must be stored somewhere other than on `loop()`'s stack. They could be declared `static`, or moved to the module outside. Outside is better IMHO, especially in the constrained Arduino environment.

You also need to clear the accumulator after you finish an average. This is the simplest form of an averaging filter, where you sum up fixed length blocks of N samples, and then use that average each Nth sample.

I believe this fragment (untested) will work for you:

```
long AvrNum;
int counter;

void setup() {
  AvrNum = 0;
  counter = 0;
}

void loop() {                    

  AvrNum += cs_4_2.capacitiveSensor(30);
  counter++;

  if (counter == 10) {
    long AvrCap = AvrNum/10;
    Serial.println(AvrCap);
    counter = 0;
    AvrNum = 0;
  }
}
```

I provided a `setup()`, although it is redundant with the C++ language's guarantee that the global variables begin life initialized to 0.

Comment: Looks like its reading everything correctly! Thanks for the help. Using a global variable makes a lot of sense. I found another solution with this for loop, could you tell me it this checks out....I put it as another answer...

Answer (score 2):

your line `if (counter = 10)` is invalid.  It should be `if (counter == 10)`

The first sets counter to 10 and will (of course) evaluate to true.
The second tests for counter equal to 10 and will not evaluate to true until counter is, indeed, equal to 10.

Also, kaylum mentions the other problem, no initialization of `AvrNum`

Comment: Ok, I did all of those things except for initialize `AvrNum` because If I initialize it to 0 then won't it loop back and delete the previously stored sensor data? I wanted to get an average of about ten readings or so.

Comment: Initializing `AvrNum` is a necessity. Yes, you will lose your previous data - to solve that problem, do `if ((counter % 10) == 0)` and `AvrCap = AvrNum / counter;`)

Answer (score 0):

This is What I ended up coming up with after spending some more time on it. After some manual calc it gets all the data.

```
long AvrArray [9];

      for(int x = 0; x <= 10; x++){
       if(x == 10){
          long AvrMes = (AvrArray[0] + AvrArray[1] + AvrArray[2] + AvrArray[3] + AvrArray[4] + AvrArray[5] + AvrArray[6] + AvrArray[7] + AvrArray[8] + AvrArray[9]);
          long AvrCap = AvrMes/x;
          Serial.print("\t");
          Serial.println(AvrCap);
          x = 0;
        }

       AvrArray[x] = cs_4_2.capacitiveSensor(30);
       Serial.println(AvrArray[x]);

         delay(500);
```

Comment: This is badly broken, and deserves its own question so that it can be dissected and explained why. You can link to that question from this one, which is the usual way that follow-up questions are best handled on SO.

Comment: Gotcha! I'll do that in just a sec